# Use of uninitialized value $Row[3] in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: perl, otrs

Im currently get this error on my OTRS system and i cant figure out what is happening.

Error on syslog:

> There was an error executing Execute() in Kernel::System::Console::Command::Maint::Survey::RequestsDelete: Use of uninitialized value $Row[3] in concatenation (.) or string at /opt/otrs/Kernel/System/Console/Command/Maint/Survey/RequestsDelete.pm line 132.

Part of code which faulty:

```
# fetch the result        
while ( my @Row = $DBObject->FetchrowArray() ) {

                my $Result = join(
                    ' ', "Survey:" . $Row[0] . "\t",
                    "TicketNumber:" . $Row[1] . "\t",
                    "SendTime:" . $Row[2] . "\t",
                    "VoteTime:" . $Row[3] . "\t",
                    "CreateTime:" . $Row[4] . "\t"
                );

                $Self->Print("$Result\n");
            }
```

Comment: It means the variable `$Row[3]` has not been assigned a value or has been assigned a value of `undef`. Might be `warnings` are enabled, that's why this message is popping out (which is good).

Comment: a quiet strange because i cant see this row on frontend. Besides, i run RequestsDelete on ssh and no errors occurs and logs still empty.
Print here: https://imgur.com/73tEW8E

Comment: Irrespective of this warning, the `$Result` value should print in the console.

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Can you verify the db schema for the table accessed via `$DBObject->FetchrowArray()`?  First thing is to ensure those fields actually exist.

Whether you can validate the schema or not, it's good practice to perform validation against the fields and provide a default value if not e.g.

```
$Row[3] = '' if not defined $Row[3];
```

or

```
$Row[3] = '-' if not defined $Row[3];
```

or

```
$Row[3] = 'not defined' if not defined $Row[3];
```

or

```
$Row[3] //= 'not defined';
```

Then your code is protected against missing data.

Just use a default value that makes sense for the output.

Comment: @ikegami That's an excellent one!  I tend to shy away from the terser examples since they sometimes confuse folks new to Perl, but I personally like that syntax.